# MongoDB aggregate group and count nested array

Tags: mongodb

I'm new with MongoDB and try aggregate with this data

```
db.probes.insertMany([
{ '_id' : 1, 'item' : 'abc', 'ts' : new Date('2014-03-01T08:00:00Z'), 'probs' : ['P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4', 'P5'] },
{ '_id' : 2, 'item' : 'jkl', 'ts' : new Date('2014-03-01T09:00:00Z'), 'probs' : ['P2', 'P3', 'P4', 'P5'] },
{ '_id' : 3, 'item' : 'xyz', 'ts' : new Date('2014-03-15T09:00:00Z'), 'probs' : ['P3', 'P4', 'P5'] },
{ '_id' : 4, 'item' : 'xyz', 'ts' : new Date('2014-04-04T11:21:39.736Z'), 'probs' : ['P4', 'P5'] },
{ '_id' : 5, 'item' : 'abc', 'ts' : new Date('2014-04-04T21:23:13.331Z'), 'probs' : ['P5'] }
]);
```

I want to group and count the nested array, how possible to get output like this?

// output 1

```
{
    'P1' : 1, 'P2' : 2, 'P3' : 3, 'P4' : 4, 'P5' : 5,
}
```

// output 2

```
{
    { 'P1' : 1, 'ts' : { 2014-03-01T08:00:00Z } },
    { 'P2' : 2, 'ts' : { 2014-03-01T08:00:00Z, 2014-03-01T09:00:00Z } },
    { 'P3' : 3, 'ts' : { 2014-03-01T08:00:00Z, 2014-03-01T09:00:00Z, 2014-03-15T09:00:00Z } }
    { 'P4' : 4, 'ts' : { 2014-03-01T08:00:00Z, 2014-03-01T09:00:00Z, 2014-03-15T09:00:00Z, 2014-04-04T11:21:39.736Z } } }
}
```

// output 3

```
{
    { 'P1' : { 'count' : 1, 'ts' : { 2014-03-01T08:00:00Z } },
    { 'P2' : { 'count' : 2, 'ts' : { 2014-03-01T08:00:00Z, 2014-03-01T09:00:00Z } },
    { 'P3' : { 'count' : 3, 'ts' : { 2014-03-01T08:00:00Z, 2014-03-01T09:00:00Z, 2014-03-15T09:00:00Z } }
    { 'P4' : { 'count' : 4, 'ts' : { 2014-03-01T08:00:00Z, 2014-03-01T09:00:00Z, 2014-03-15T09:00:00Z, 2014-04-04T11:21:39.736Z } } }
    { 'P5' : { 'count' : 5, 'ts' : { 2014-03-01T08:00:00Z, 2014-03-01T09:00:00Z, 2014-03-15T09:00:00Z, 2014-04-04T11:21:39.736Z, 2014-04-04T21:23:13.331Z } } }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to combine [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/), [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) and [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/). For example:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$probs"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$probs",
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      ts: {
        $addToSet: "$ts"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/c4O5zfxhRCl

You can use this as a base for all of the formats you want.

Comment: Your guidance can help me save a lot of time. thank you and have a nice day.

Comment: @psodaz No problem. Please mark the answer as accepted, gotta get those internet points. Thank you!